# Python - Add comment and a column to txt (tsv) file

Tags: python, dataframe

There is a txt file (tap separated) with comments like:

```
[header]
This file is generated by Bingbong Kim
user name : user
user gender : male
user age : 45
[data]
user_item        color        price
item1            red          10
item2            black        20
item3            green        10
item4            blue         15
```

I would like to add one more comment(#user country) and insert a new column that all values are same like:

```
[header]
This file is generated by Bingbong Kim
user name : user
user gender : male
user age : 45
user country : US
[data]
user_item        color        price        check
item1            red          10           true
item2            black        20           true
item3            green        10           true
item4            blue         15           true
```

Now I did :

```
import pandas as pd

# save the comments in a list
header_list = []
temp_report = open('report.txt')
for i, line in enumerate(temp_report):
    header_list.append(line)
    if i == 7:
        temp_report.close()
        break

# create a dataframe without the comments
report = pd.read_csv('report.txt', skiprows=6, sep='\t')

# insert a column to the dataframe
report['check'] = "true"    #all values are same

# write the comment first and then write the changed dataframe
f = open('new_report.txt', 'a')
for comment in header_list:
    f.write(comment)
report.to_csv(f, sep='\t', index=False)
f.close()
```

I think there seems to be another good way. It takes about 50 second per a txt file because the txt file is too big. How can I improve it?

Comment: unrelated: You don't need to close the file at the last `f.close()`. 'with ..' context would do that for you. 
Can you explain how are you iterating between different text files? I see you are opening the file in append mode. That would seek to the end of file and may consume a lot of time if the size of the file grows huge.

Comment: @Sumit Deshmukh Thank you for the advice. And I found that my code has a big problem. the comments goes to the end of the txt file. Is it because of the append mode? I updates the code. I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: now it works good.

Comment: That does not appear to be a TSV file (tab separated value file). It has some kind of customization that gives it sections and embeds data in the TSV format inside one of them.